# Why final memory state equals to the last hidden state of entire hidden state sequence?

Tags: tensorflow, long-short-term-memory

when `return_sequences=True` and `return_state=True`, a TensorFlow LSTM outputs the hidden states of the LSTM cell along with the memory state and hidden state of the cell as described in Tensorflow docs

```
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
whole_seq_output, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = lstm(inputs)
```

So in my understanding, the last timestep of each item of `whole_seq_output` should be the same as `final_carry_state`, but it turned out it's not. Could someone please explain to me why?

```
whole_seq_output[:, -1, :] - final_carry_state # this should be equals to 0, but its not
whole_seq_output[:, -1, :] - final_memory_state # this equals to 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Image from wikipedia]

This image shows how an lstm cell operates (taken from Wikipedia). The carry state as implemented in tensorflow is the `c_t` which is different from the final memory state h_t (which is also the state passed as sequence output). So `seq_output - h_t = 0` and `seq_output - c_t != 0`.